# create polygon in mapbasic mapinfo

Tags: mapinfo

Create Table "parsel" (Parsel_Adi Char(10)) file "D:\data\parsel\parsel.tab" TYPE NATIVE

Charset "WindowsLatin1"

Create Map For parsel CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 28,"m", 33, 0, 0.9996, 500000, 0

Map from parsel

Set Map Layer parsel Editable On

Create Region Into Variable obj_parsel 0

Alter Object obj_parsel Node Add ( 417000, 4401000)

Alter Object obj_parsel Node Add ( 418000, 4401000)

Alter Object obj_parsel Node Add ( 417000, 4403000)

Alter Object obj_parsel Node Add ( 418000, 4400300)

Insert Into parsel(Object, Parsel_Adi) Values (obj_parsel, "SEMIH")

Commit Table parsel Interactive

this is my code. I try to create parsel table but it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no valid end node for a region. A region is closed by a node the same as the start node. try adding;

Alter Object obj_parsel Node Add ( 417000, 4401000)